# Pandas how to get the index of row?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('traj2_Binarization.csv', sep=",", index_col="NAME")

for index, row in data.iterrows():
    print(row)
```

```
    -----results------
    RUNX3            0
    ROGDI            0
    FSTL3            0
    MOCOS            0
    PDCD7            1
    MYO15A           0
    MYO9B            0
    MAP1LC3A         0
    TBC1D19          0
    ASIC1            0
    RAP1A            0
    ARAP3            0
    IQSEC2           0
    HIVEP3           0
```

Here, how can I make the results converted to below?

```
RUNX3 = False
ROGDI = False
FSTL3 = False
MOCOS = False
PDCD7 = True
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `f-string`s with selecting one item Series to scalar by `row["NAME"]` and converting to `bool`:

```
#python 3.6 +
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    print(f'{index} = {bool(row["RUNX3"])}')
```

```
#python bellow 3.6
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    print('{} = {}'.format(index, bool(row["RUNX3"])))

RUNX3 = False
ROGDI = False
FSTL3 = False
MOCOS = False
PDCD7 = True
MYO15A = False
MYO9B = False
MAP1LC3A = False
TBC1D19 = False
ASIC1 = False
RAP1A = False
ARAP3 = False
IQSEC2 = False
HIVEP3 = False
```

---

```
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    print(index, bool(row["RUNX3"]))

RUNX3 False
ROGDI False
FSTL3 False
MOCOS False
PDCD7 True
MYO15A False
MYO9B False
MAP1LC3A False
TBC1D19 False
ASIC1 False
RAP1A False
ARAP3 False
IQSEC2 False
HIVEP3 False
```

And for boolean `Series` use [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
s = data["RUNX3"].astype(bool)
print (s)
RUNX3       False
ROGDI       False
FSTL3       False
MOCOS       False
PDCD7        True
MYO15A      False
MYO9B       False
MAP1LC3A    False
TBC1D19     False
ASIC1       False
RAP1A       False
ARAP3       False
IQSEC2      False
HIVEP3      False
Name: NAME, dtype: bool
```

Comment: I am a new, thank you but I had an error that is ---> KeyError: 'NAME'

Comment: @이춘경 - how working if change `row["NAME"]` to `row` ? What is `print (data.columns)` ?

Comment: It's like that Index(['RUNX3', 'ROGDI', 'FSTL3', 'MOCOS', 'PDCD7', 'MYO15A', 'MYO9B'......])

Comment: @이춘경 - I think need change `Name` to column name, you can check it by `print (data.columns)`

Comment: I edited and added traj2_Binarization.csv image file. Could you check what the problem is?

Comment: @이춘경 - so need convert all 0 and 1 to False and Trues? then use `data = data.astype(bool)`

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to @jezrael's answer, if version under 3.6:

```
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    print('%s = %s'%(index,bool(row['whatever is the column'])))
```

Or:

```
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    print('{0} = {1}'.format(index,bool(row['whatever is the column'])))
```

Or:

```
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    print(index,'=',bool(row['whatever is the column']))
```

All Output:

```
RUNX3 = False
ROGDI = False
FSTL3 = False
MOCOS = False
PDCD7 = True
MYO15A = False
MYO9B = False
MAP1LC3A = False
TBC1D19 = False
ASIC1 = False
RAP1A = False
ARAP3 = False
IQSEC2 = False
HIVEP3 = False
```